# Invalid Redirect URL in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

When i am entering http://mydomain.com in Google Drive Redirect URL then getting:

> Invalid Redirect URL

Please let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: You tagged PHP, do you mean you're using Google Drive API ? If yes, show your codes.

Comment: Nope, i am trying to set redirect url in Google Drive Console where i can get secrete key etc all n that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am referring to the console, where you create and get your keys for your projects:

https://cloud.google.com/console

Your URL to localhost is the box "Redirect URIs"

In your code, then you have:

```
$redirectURI = 'http://localhost';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId($clientID);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectURI);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));
```

These must match, or you'll get this error every time.